# HTTP over Winsock: fonts don't load until user presses "stop loading" button in their browser

Tags: c++, sockets, vector, binary, winsock

When sending TTF files over HTTP, the font doesn't appear until the user manually presses the button to stop loading the page.

Let's use Inter font as an example. I read the file from disk to binary using `vector<unsigned char>`.

```
// Read file as binary
FILE* f;            // File handle
unsigned long flen; // File length in unsigned long because file length is always >= 0
             
f = fopen(c_internal_path, "rb"); // Open file in "r(ead)b(inary)" mode

if (!f) {   // If file not open print error to console and terminate function
    fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file %s", c_internal_path); 
    http_code = 500;
    content = Util::stringToUCharVector(HTTP_ERROR_500);
}
else {
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
    flen = ftell(f);
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);

    content.resize(flen + 1); 
    std::fread(&content[0], flen, 1, f);

    fwrite(content.data(), 1, content.size(), stdout); // Write file contents to console
    fclose(f);
```

Then I take the `data()` of this vector and add it to the output `stringstream`:

```
// Compose HTTP response:
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << "HTTP/1.1 " << http_response.http_code << " OK\r\n";
    oss << "Cache-Control: no-cache, private\r\n";
    oss << "Content-Type: " << FHTTPMIME::MimeToString(mime_type) << "\r\n"; // use MimeToString() to convert enum MIME to string MIME
    oss << "Content-Length: " << http_response.content.size() << "\r\n"; // use size of 'content' vector<unsigned char>
    oss << "\r\n";
    oss << http_response.content.data(); // access vector data() for content char[]
```

We get a response like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Content-Type: font/ttf
Content-Length: 803385

<binary data of the file>
```

Then send the response to the client by:

```
// Convert ostringstream to string
    std::string output = oss.str();
    int size = output.size() + 1;

// Send 'output.c_str()' char* of size 'size' to 'clientSocket'
sendToClient(clientSocket, output.c_str(), size);
```

The size of the file is `803384` bytes. What can I be doing wrong in this situation for `ttf` font to not load properly?

I tried adding `+1` to `Content-Length` and null-terminating (`'\0'`) the binary `vector`, but nothing helped.

**EDIT** Everything works as intended for HTML, CSS, but **not** for TTF, JPG, JPEG, WEBP and so on, even though I use the correct MIME types.

Comment: Only describing your secret code in natural language doesn't provide much help. Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Content-length is 803385 when the size is 803384? Seems like an off by 1 error, and the client is waiting for that last byte.

Comment: @EmanuelP Might be that nul byte the OP added...

Comment: And is the socket getting closed, after transmitting either 803385 and 803384 bytes?

Comment: @MikeCAT I have added the code for better understanding of the problem

Comment: @EmanuelP Indeed this has been an issue which I have fixed. Everything loads, but TTFs don't load correctly as implied in the question

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Is it supposed to close? I'm using a keep-alive connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, terminating NUL is not required for binary data (not string), so remove the extra byte.

```cpp
// content.resize(flen + 1);
content.resize(flen);
```

Secondly, passing `unsigned char*` to `std::ostringstream` via `<<` operator makes it take only until first byte having value `0x00`. You should use [`write`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write) function to explicitly specify the size of (binary) data.

```cpp
//oss << http_response.content.data();
oss.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(http_response.content.data()), http_response.content.size());
```

Finally, remove another extra byte.

```cpp
//int size = output.size() + 1;
int size = output.size();
```

Comment: Indeed, after I applied your advice everything works as it should: TTF, JPG/JPEG and PNG. Thank you, I'm glad the community has people like you, Mike